# R Markdown automatically makes title

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I'm about to write my master's thesis in R Markdown and when I knit to pdf there is the standard title which one gets in LaTeX with '\maketitle'.
The autor, the title and the name. Quite ugly.
I don't know how to delete that ...
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

You can modify your [YAML header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) in many ways. Please read the [PDF Documents](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) section within RStudio's RMarkdown page.

## Reproducible Example

When you first create an .rmd file, this is the default YAML header:

````
---
title: "Default_YAML"
author: "Daffy Duck"
date: "2/17/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

# Header
Some text.
```{r}
df <- read.csv( file = "somefilepath.csv" )
```
````

You can customize what does and does not appear within your YAML header. Below is an example of me deleting the entire thing:

````
# Header
Some text.
```{r}
df <- read.csv( file = "somefilepath.csv" )
```
````